# Undefined variable [CodeIgniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter

both variables are undefined($usuario and $senha) :(

this code is suposed to do login, but the model isn't receiving the variables

Controller

```
public function login(){

    $this->load->model('Usuario_model');
    $this->Usuario_model->usuario = $this->input->post('usuario');
    $this->Usuario_model->senha = sha1($this->input->post('senha'));
    $dados = $this->Usuario_model->login();
    foreach($dados AS $row){
        $level = $row->level;
        $usuario = $row->login;
    }
    if(($dados)){
        $newdata = array(
           'usuario'  => "$usuario",
           'level'     => $level,
           'logged_in' => TRUE
       );
         $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
         $session = $this->session->all_userdata();  
       redirect("index.php/voe/index");
    }
}
```

Model

```
public function login(){ 

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'");
        $query = $query->result();
         return $query;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you [read up on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: To format code, highlight the block, and click the `{}` button (*not* the `""` button).

Comment: You need to pass `$usuario` and `$senha` to the `login()` function as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

There's an indication from these two lines:

```
$this->Usuario_model->usuario = $this->input->post('usuario');
$this->Usuario_model->senha = sha1($this->input->post('senha'));
```

that there are variables inside of the `Usuario-model` that you have accessed and stored, but the `login()` function is trying to access variables inside of the scope of the function, not the scope of the model. Using `$this->` will allow you to access the private, public, or protected variables of the class that the function lives in.  Make sure you try:

```
public function login(){ 
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login = '".$this->usuario."' AND senha = '".$this->senha."'");
    $query = $query->result();
    return $query;
}
```

To use a PDO-like approach, [as per the CI docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html), you should instead do:

```
public function login() {
    $query = $this->db->query(
        'SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login = ? AND senha = ?',
        array($this->usuario, $this->senha)
    )
    $query = $query->result();
    return $query;
}
```

This will give you safer queries with escaped user values.